# INstalling firefox nightly

Tags: linux, firefox, installation

I run the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
```

I get the following error.

```
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I'm new to Linux - what does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can run a few commands to download and install firefox nightly on Debian.

<sub>Note: these commands will download and install the en-US version, if you need a different version, copy and paste the download link from the firefox website into the terminal for the following `wget` command URL but be sure the URL is within single quote marks when you run the command or the download won't work.</sub>

**PART ONE**

**First**, download the latest version of Firefox nightly using the following command:

```
wget -o firefox.tar.bz2 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-nightly-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US'
```

**Next**, extract the file using the `tar` command:

```
tar xvf firefox.tar.bz2
```

After the file is finished extracting, run the following command to move the files to the proper directory:

```
sudo mv firefox /opt
```

and enter your password and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when prompted.

**Now**, run the following command to link your files:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox-nightly
```

Firefox is currently installed. You can run firefox by executing the following command in a terminal:

```
firefox-nightly &
```

---

**PART TWO**

The following method will create a "desktop file" so that Firefox will show up in your list of installed applications and you won't have to run firefox from the terminal.

**First**, run the following command to create and edit the file using the `nano` text editor:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/firefox-nightly.desktop
```

**Next**, copy and paste the following contents into the terminal:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Nightly
Comment=Web Browser
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
```

**Now**, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

**Finally**, log out and log back in to refresh your list of installed applications.

---

**PART THREE (only needed if you have disabled automatic updates)**

To update Firefox nightly, click on the "hamburger" menu icon.

On the dropdown menu, click **Help** > **About Nightly** and it should show an option if Firefox is not up to date.

---

[Click here for more info on the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Firefox).

Comment: You may have to change permissions on the firefox directory in `/opt` in order to receive updates. If updates work fine then this is no problem. Otherwise, something like `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/firefox` and/or maybe also `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/firefox/*` should allow updates to work.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SuperUser
There is no need for adding a PPA to ubuntu. You can just go [here](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-nightly-latest-ssl&os=linux64&lang=en-US) and download the latest version of Firefox Nightly onto the hard drive.

Locate the file, right-click and select **extract here** to extract the archive.
Now open a terminal and navigate to the extracted folder location by using `cd` command.

Now use the command (running just once is enough)

```
sudo chmod +x firefox
```

This will grant the executable file permissions to that file. 
Now type

```
firefox
```

This will open Firefox Nightly.
Hope this helps!